# Proofs involving orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Suppose that $V$ is an inner product space.

(a) Show that if $\{e_1, . . . , e_n\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$ , then $$||v||^2=\sum_{i=1}^{n}|\langle v|e_i\rangle|^2\quad \quad \text{for every $v\in V.$}$$
(b) Suppose that $\{e_1, . . . , e_k\}$ is an orthonormal set in $V$ (not necessarily a basis), and let $v ∈ V$. Show that if
$$||v||^2=\sum_{i=1}^{k}|\langle v|e_i\rangle|^2\quad \quad \text{for every $v\in V$}$$
then $v = \sum_{i=1}^{k}⟨v | e_i⟩e_i.$

I tried to use the reconstruction formula but am not getting anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), write $v = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle e_i$ and find $\langle v,v\rangle$ using the conjugate-linearity of the dot-product.

For (b), extend the set to an orthonormal basis and note that if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n |\langle v,e_i\rangle|^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k |\langle v,e_i\rangle|^2
$$
with $n > k$, then $\langle v,e_i\rangle = 0$ for all $i > k$.

Comment: for part a. i did what you said and ended up with $LHS=\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle  \sum_{i=1}^n \overline{\langle v,e_i\rangle}$. What do I do next to finish it off.

Comment: How did you end up with that?! You should have got $$\langle v,v \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v,e_i\rangle \overline{\langle v,e_i\rangle}$$

Comment: Check now. I miss typed before

Comment: So it is what you got. How do I proceed from there?